# Oscillating sums II

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\left\{a_k\right\}_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ and $\left\{b_k\right\}_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ be two positive decreasing sequences such that $c_1a_k\leqslant b_k\leqslant c_2 a_k$ for all $k$ for some positive constants $c_1,c_2$. Let $\epsilon>0$ and $f>0$ a function such that $$\sum_{k=0}^na_k\sin(k\epsilon)\geqslant f(n).$$

> **Question.** Is it true that $$\sum_{k=0}^nb_k\sin(k\epsilon)\geqslant cf(n)$$ for some constant
> $c$ (independent of $n$, $\epsilon$)?

---

Without the monotonicity condition on the $a_k$'s and $b_k$'s, the answer is no, as shown in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/390785/36721).

Comment: Are you assuming that $f>0$?

Comment: Yes I am_______

Comment: This is already answered in your previous post

Comment: @username No, I have added the hypothesis that $a_k$ and $b_k$ are decreasing. I created a new post as suggested by Iosif Pinelis and I don't understand why already 3 people dislike my question just because I added that hypothesis?! There is something I don't get.

Comment: You should make the connection to your previous post clear. You are getting downvotes apparently because people do not notice the difference.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I find it a little bit harsh. I'm new to Mathoverflow and I don't know how to do that, so I just follow suggestions :)

Comment: Probably because there was 40 minutes between your two question, leaving zero time for you to try to figure it out yourself.

Comment: @username zero time? ah but it is many months I have this question, I just forgot to add that hypothesis...

Comment: In that case make sure this post has all the hypothesis required, details what you have tried, explains why small changes to the counter examples in your previous post do not work etc..

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Ok, thank you for your answer.

Comment: @coco : I have edited your post to make the connection with the previous post explicit.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Many thanks! :)

Comment: I upvoted, since the downvotes are unjustified (imo)

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks :))

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$The answer is still no (assuming you wanted $c>0$). Indeed, let
$$s_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\sin(k\ep),\quad t_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n b_k\sin(k\ep),$$
where $\ep=3\pi/4$, $a_0=b_0=10$, $a_1=1$, $b_1=9$, and $a_k=b_k=2^{-k}$ for $k\ge2$.

Then $c_1a_k\le b_k\le c_2a_k$ for $c_1=1$, $c_2=9$, and all $k\ge0$. Moreover, $s_0>0$ and $s_1=-1 + 5\sqrt2>6>0$, whence $s_n>6-\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2^{-k}>0$ for $n\ge2$. So, $s_n>0$ for all $n\ge0$. So, letting
$f(n):=s_n$ for all $n\ge0$, we get a positive function $f$ such that $s_n\le f(n)$ for all $n\ge0$. Thus, all your conditions on the $a_k$'s and $b_k$'s are satisfied.

However, $t_1=-9 + 5\sqrt2<-19/20<0$ and, moreover, $t_n<-19/20+\sum_{k=2}^\infty 2^{-k}<0$ for all $n\ge2$.  Thus, the condition $t_n\le cf(n)$ fails to hold for any $c>0$ and any $n\ge1$.

Comment: Thank you very much Iosif. This is not a good news for my calculation, I should find more hypothesis to have this lower bound.

Comment: @coco : I understand that you hoped to get positive answers to your questions. However, the answers, even though negative, seem correct and complete, and they may help you find the right conditions. So, to have a closure, are you satisfied with the answers in this sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you for taking time to find a counter example.

Comment: @coco : Why have you unaccepted this answer? Is it not a correct and complete answer to your post?

Comment: waw i'm impressed by the rapidity of your reaction. No it was not at all answering my question, i said ok to make you happy because this was just a tiny part of my research and i could not put the whole context to explain what are my a_k and b_k and \epsilon, etc. But no, my \epsilon is not 3\pi/4 and your example of a_k and b_k only differ in a_1 and b_1 which is also not my case. But of course i was not going to write a new post "Oscillating sums III" adding these facts, because you don't get that this was not just an exercise but part of my research :)

Comment: So we never know, maybe someone can find an answer one day and i would be happy to hear the solution :)

Comment: @coco : One can only answer the question that you **actually posted**. You may have had a number of additional, unstated conditions in mind, but nobody can read your mind, except yourself, can they? So I will ask you again: Is my answer not a correct and complete answer to your question -- just the way your question was actually stated? If you think the answer is not correct or complete, please let me know why you think so (without mentioning anything unstated in your post). (I do not need anyone to make me happy. I just would like them to be reasonable and fair.)